# Regularising neural networks with pre-trained weights

Tags: neural-networks, regularization, overfitting, dropout

I trained CNN to over-fit the data (close to 0 train error), it took 6 days to  train. Now I want to regularise the model using L2 or Dropout, with weights initialised from over-fitted model, will it work? or should start training again from scratch?

Comment: “Will it work”—will it run? Yes. Will it perform better than it does already? Not necessarily. Are you asking which initialization will perform better with the same training regimen?

Comment: yes, which will give better test performance?

Comment: There's no hard-and-fast rule here.